# shrink windows and extand ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize

I tried to shrink Windows and then expand Ubuntu.
I did shrink Windows from within Windows and I boot Ubuntu from USB to add that unallocated space to Ubuntu but I cant do it. 
The option doesn't show.
Any idea how to complete the process?

[image]

Comment: Extend /sda3, move swap partition to the end of the free space. then you can grow your linux partition.

Comment: how can i move it the partition sda3?

Comment: you have to grow it not move it

Answer (score 2):

this is because the item you are trying to expand is inside a 'container'... the 'extended' partition...You have to extended the sda3 partition first so there is room for sda5 to expand.