# Shrinking Windows' partition on a SSD and installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I have a Lenovo machine with 1TB (~1000GB) SSD - Unpartitioned. It contains roughly 100 GB of Windows OS and some local user files (the machine is new).

Are the following changes advised?

1. Shrink the Windows partition to (say) 500 GB: This will result in a 500 GB unallocated partition (let's call it: UA).
2. Format UA using Ubuntu installing process: Create a 4GB swap and the rest /home.
3. Proceed to install Ubuntu 22.04 in UA.

I came across this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986934/shrink-windows-and-extand-ubuntu), which is not about a fresh installation of Ubuntu, but the expansion of an existing Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 3):

Do like this:

1. Shrink the windows partition from the windows disk utility

- Now you will have some unallocated space

3. Boot ubuntu and launch the installer
4. Choose install ubuntu alongside windows

Done

P.s. If you want to install with manual partitioning create an ext4 partition on the unallocated space with the mount point / and install.

Don't make the swap partition, the new ubuntu installer automatically creates a swap file

Comment: If using separate /home, you still now need / (root) as 40 or 50GB as Ubuntu now uses snaps. I am using Kubuntu and no snaps and use about 15GB in my 40GB /, all my data is in other partitions. Be sure to install in UEFI boot mode. Depending on brand/model system, you may need to change some UEFI settings. install overview: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview